# Rest API 401 Error with JIRA

Tags: api, rest, jira, unauthorized

I tried using the REST API to fetch some information, and it seemed to work perfectly fine on VBA (Within Excel)

But when I try the same thing on Java I get a 401 error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://y.y.y/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/PROJ-123
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
at com.jpmchase.jiraextraction.apiHandler.getHTML(apiHandler.java:61)
at com.jpmchase.jiraextraction.apiHandler.main(apiHandler.java:19)
```

Similarly when I try this in python 2.7

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
 return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
 response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
 return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
 result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
 raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you passing in the username/password when connecting. The Unauthorized indicates it can validate the user that is attempting to connect?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I'm passing them in as the incorrect arguments? Let me poke around a little further.

Comment: jira-python has good docs on this, and you can see what it send

Comment: Ah, it seems like part of my credential bytstring was malformed. This as the main cause. Thanks @Jason

Comment: You have to send the HTTP Basic Auth headers with each and every query.

Comment: @Koshinae is there any way to save a session? I don't think it matters much, but out of curiosity.

Comment: When I used `curl`, I used the --cookie-jar option.